# node js - Huge TLSWrap objects in heapdump snapshots

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks

I'm running a node.js express application on production. After a few hours of running, in a heap snapshot I can see that there are more than 10 huge TLSWrap objects per worker (these are the largest objects in the application).

### Some Technical Aspects

- I'm running forever with the cluster module (2 workers).
- The application runs inside an AWS EC2 large instance.
- Most of the tasks per request are getting data from redis and sending some requests (events) to another server.
- Normal memory usage: ~450MB, after a few hours suddenly: 3.5GB (then there is too much latency and my load balancer removes this machine). See [Memory usage graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufmGY.png).
- Normal CPU usage: 16%, during the memory leak: 99%.

### What I've Tried Already

- **Code refactoring** with memory leaks problems in mind (closures, big objects and minimal string concatenation.
- **Upgrading node** all the way from v0.12.7, v4.1.1, v4.1.2 and v4.2.0.

### Some Interesting Insights

- The growth of memory usage is not linear, but exponential and happend **suddenly and very fast**.
- I have both permanent instances and also auto-scaling instances (same type) and this memory leak occurs at the **same time** on all machines.
- Traffic (# requests) is not higher than usual during the memory leak.
- I've read that sometimes these problems can be the result of continuing the application running after **uncaughtException**, but my uncaughtException handler just logs the error and then immediately calls process.exit() - Isn't that the same as when node crashes and the forever automatically restarts it?
- I have another application that's:

  - Running from the same AWS EC2 AMI.
  - Has larger number of requests per second.
  - Has the uncaughtException handler (with process.exit()), too.
  - *But no memory leaks at all*!

Any ideas?
Thanks,

Comment: Just wanted to say I'm having similar problems and also looking for a solution.

Comment: Same here, please let us know if you found a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that your memory leak is caused by something other than the TLSWrap objects, probably in your application layer.

According to this recently closed node issue, https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/4250, TLSWrap has been incorrectly reporting its size as a large number (a pointer cast to an int). The actual size of TSLWrap objects is much smaller.

I was also seeing very large TLSWrap objects in my heapdumps, but after upgrading to node 5.3.0 (which includes the fix, https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/4268), I can confirm that they are now correctly shown as quite small in my heapdumps.

Comment: I am using node version 4.2.3 and I am getting memory pile up due to TLSWrap objects when I try to upload file to S3 bucket. did you find a proper solution why heap snap shot show huge object for TLSWrap ?